# How to use the text found by regex somewhere else in the code

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this line of code

```
thePage.html(thePage.html().replace(/DECC([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{3})[A-Z]-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/g, '<a class="DeccDocumentId" onclick="TG.DECC.EDRMSLinks.redirectToDocument()">$1$2$3</a>'));
```

I want to replace the text found by regex with a link that still uses that text, ive already attempted (most likely incorrectly) a backreference in the form of $1$2$3 but its not working.

If its any help the text im trying to replace is

DECCMIA-1-1

DECCMIC-1-103

DECCFCSE-92-12

and it turns out to be like this

MI$2$3

MI$2$3

FCS$2$3

Comment: $n things refer to groups (=parens) in your regexp. Since you have only one pair of parents, $2 and $3 don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In replacing $& refers to the entire match, $1, $2,.. refer to individual capture groups inside the match. You use only one capture group in your expression.

```
/DECC([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{3})[A-Z]-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/g
([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{3}) // $1 refers to this capture group.
```

But you try to refer to three when replacing.